# get response header robot framework

Tags: http, http-headers, robotframework

I'm trying to get the response header that named com.coradiant.appvis  in robot framework
there are no resources that can help ,, this is my code

```
*** Settings ***
Library            HttpLibrary.HTTP
Test Setup      Create HTTP Context     ${HOST}

*** Variables ***
${PORT}         80
${HOST}       http://vw-tlv-idnqa31${PORT}/EventsApps/EventsApps/WebForm.aspx
${APPVIS_HEADER}


*** Test Cases ***
Checking Appvis test
    Get the appvis response header

*** Keywords ***
Get the appvis response header
${APPVIS_HEADER} =        get response header   com.coradiant.appvis
Log     ${APPVIS_HEADER}
```

Comment: What does the log message actually show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make a request before you can get the header. You can use the [GET](http://peritus.github.io/robotframework-httplibrary/HttpLibrary.html#GET) keyword to make the request, assuming you need the headers for a GET request.